# streamreader network use memory on host computer

Tags: c#, networking, filestream

In C#, I'm using a FileStream to open files across a network that are being hosted on another Windows box, and I was curious what impact this would have on the computer hosting the file.  Does the accessing computer simply grab it chunk by chunk from the HDD directly?  Does the host computer put the file into memory?  I guess this is sort of outside of the actual programming area as this may be something that is more at the OS level, but I figured I would ask here.

My main concerns are if the host computer actually has to open the files into memory to send them across, I may use up its memory if accessing a lot of files simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Windows uses SMB protocol for remote file read/write. Reference information can be found [at msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365233(v=vs.85).aspx).

It will not load everything on the host server's memory, transfer will be streamed. Even if you call File.ReadAllBytes() on the client, host server will stream it to the client through SMB protocol.

Memory utilization on host will depend on the number of clients connected at a time. More clients simultaneously transferring file would naturally mean more memory utilization on the host. Other than that, individual file transfer itself should have very little impact on additional memory allocation in the host.